# change window's href on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I am trying to change window's href on every refresh.

This is some url I have- `http://localhost:2090/Meeting/CreateMeeting/?scope=&code=vGgoJvYi`

Now I wished to have it as- `http://localhost:2090/Meeting/CreateMeeting/`

**Tried-**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.location.href = "/Meeting/CreateMeeting/";
    }
```

This didn't work-

So I tried it with an hidden anchor-

```
<a href="/Meeting/CreateMeeting" id="click-url"></a>
```

and then-

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        $('#click-url').click();
    }
```

But I failed with this also.
How Do I make this url without parameters ?

**Edit-**

I am using some webservice to accept parameters from current url. So basically I have some form and on its submit it generates this url with parameter after redirecting from some api. My further process depends on this url. 
if you note at url-

```
?scope=&code=vGgoJvYi
```

For every request from user that web api generates `&code` and it is unique.
If user tries to refresh the page then this code can only be coming after re-submitting the form. So further process is only be done with this generated code.

This is why I am trying to change the url without parameters because this  `?scope=&code=vGgoJvYi` will be coming after redirected from webApi.

Comment: Why on the `onbeforeunload` event ?

Comment: @NicolasAlbert, Because as soon as user refreshes the page I wish to change the url

Comment: Refresh using `F5` ?

Comment: @NicolasAlbert, Exactly!

Comment: Can't you just do it `onload`? Or are the parameters required the first time you visit the page?

Comment: @Jerodev, I have clarified it in edit.